# How to get the slimmer iOS Safari Smart App Banner?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari, smartbanner

We have a requirement to supply the smaller banner.

I can see that, after I install the app, the smart banners for some sites like Amazon are smaller than those for others like Best buy. Is there something specific that amazon is doing to get that smaller banner. Below are the meta tags for both

**Amazon**

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=297606951, app-argument=com.amazon.mobile.shopping://amazon.com?chgexp=MSHOP&amp;dl_sid=135-6432352-2690956, affiliate-data=ct=iPhone%20Gateway%20Page%20Nav%20Placement%20Banner&amp;pt=17789">
```

Screenshot
[image: Amazon's smaller banner]

**Best Buy**

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=314855255">
```

Screenshot
[image: Best Buy's larger banner]

I added the app-argument and iTunes affiliate attributes too, but that doesn't seems to help.

Comment: This is not a UX question, we have a requirement to supply the meta tag for the smaller banner.

Comment: my apologies, I have retracted the close vote. That being said you can reword the question a little bit to make it clear that you are asking technical information about how to achieve a smaller banner.

Comment: Done, thanks for looking out :)

Comment: you need some tags to increase your question visibility: maybe android/ios or the framework you develop your application or the api for getting the banner. I am not familiar with web/app development, but I am sure there must be higher visibility tags that apply to your question.

Comment: take a look at [other questions tagged smartbanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smartbanner) and see what other tags apply to your question

Comment: @Raj Did you find out what controls this "small banner"? I got the same question.

Comment: not yet, I am awaiting a response too

Comment: @Raj Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This is super strange indeed. GitHub's metatag (slim banner): `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1477376905">`, Snapchat's (fat banner): `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=447188370">`.

Comment: @ruohola That's because they use universal links

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov What is a "universal link"? Can you add that as a complete answer? :)